# Rails, set user role on sign up with devise using hidden fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a single devise user model. A users role can be: A, B, or admin.

When signing up for the first time, I would like to set the users role based on one of 2 buttons - Button A, or Button B. I will then customise the website based on those roles.

My current attempt is to link each button (A or B) to separate pages with devise forms with hidden fields that include either A or B.

Currently I'm getting unpermitted params :role in my logs when doing so.
Heres my Users devise controller:

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < 
    Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
    before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

    protected

    # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_sign_up_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
    end

    # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_account_update_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:role])
    end

  end
```

I also am unsure if this way of setting a role is safe in respect that a bad guy my be able to set their role as an admin somehow this way.

So I am guessing there is a safer and or easier way of doing things here.

Form - one has hidden field for B and one has A.

```
     <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :password %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :role, value: 'A' %>
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: I'd post some view code to make this question a little clearer :) Does sound to me like it lacks on the security front from what's there so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you should never, ever, accept permissions information in a sign-up form.

What would prevent the user from changing the hidden HTML input for `role` value to `admin` or other? I'm assuming you're using the `role` column for additional permissions information.

I'd suggest you:

1. Don't accept role params from the from
2. Use a separate column to specify visual layouts than permissions, as this will probably lead to conflicting concerns eventually

If you're bound to use the `role` attribute as your code mentions, I'd suggest setting the value manually in your controller based on a non-persisted value passed in the form.

Form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :layout, value: 'A' %>
```

Controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_action :set_layout, only: [:create]

  protected

  def set_layout
    @resource.update(role: selected_layout)
  end

  # This will whitelist the possible options
  def selected_layout
    ["A", "Other"].find { |layout_option| layout_option == params[:layout] }
  end
end
```